# Issue with Bootstrap reference and font reference from VS to VSTS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, azure-devops

I am not able to check-in the bootstrap reference form vs to vsts and getting an error as below.

> C:\Users\128185\TFS\NewHydrocyclone\NewHydrocyclone\NewHydrocyclone\NewHydrocyclone\Content\bootstrap-datetimepicker.css:
>   Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\128185\TFS\NewHydrocyclone\NewHydrocyclone\NewHydrocyclone\NewHydrocyclone\Content\bootstrap-datetimepicker.css'.

Requesting for the suggestions on this.

Comment: Can you with absolute certainty confirm that this file at this exact path exists? Sorry for asking but you haven't confirmed this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure these files are existing.

Secondly, move the project to other folder instead of the user’s folder (e.g. D:\Project)